# how to make css stylesheet to work in reactjs if components are in seperate component folder

Tags: reactjs

How do i make index.css stylesheet to work .I have all my components in a components folder inside src and it works fine but index.css doesn't seem to work.
I am listing all the different files here :
  index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/app';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

app.js inside components

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import App1 from './app1';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <App1/>
        <App1/>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and app1.js inside components folder

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class App1 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div >

        <h1> hello </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App1;
```

and index.css

```
.h1{
  font: italic;
  color: red;
}
```

In my app1.js , i render a simple header but it css is not getting into action.

Comment: it seems to be ok, I think there is something missing in your webpack configuration. Please share the module section.

Comment: het @ArnoldGandarillas i created it using create react-app thing .sure

Comment: try `h1` instead `.h1` in your index.css note the **.** at the beginning of it. With the dot you are telling apply the rules to the class instead to the tag.

Comment: @satyajeet jha -- You've asked several questions on the last couple of weeks and have not accepted any answer as correct. If your question was answered, consider marking the answers as accepted so that users know that your problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
h1 {
  font: italic;
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Grzegorz answer should solve the problem, but I wanted to expand on the why.

Your index.css file contains a class name .h1. To apply it to an HTML element need to add the class to the element.

app1.js:

```
<h1 className='h1'> hello </h1>
```

This is the same as plain old HTML/CSS. However note that you need to use 'className' instead of 'class' in react. HTML attributes are camel-case in jsx. And class is a reserved word.

If you do mean to override the base style of the h1 element, you need to remove the .(dot).

index.css

```
h1 {
  font: italic;
  color: red;
}
```